# Get content of a DIV using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two DIV's called DIV1 and DIV2 and DIV1 consists of dynamic content and DIV2 is empty. I need content of DIV1 to be displayed in DIV2. How can I do it.

I coded in below manner which is not working. Anybody please correct it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var MyDiv1 = Document.getElementById('DIV1');
   var MyDiv2 = Document.getElementById('Div2');
   MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv2; 

</script>
<body>
<div id="DIV1">
 // Some content goes here.
</div>

<div id="DIV2">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

(1) Your `<script>` tag should be placed before the closing `</body>` tag. Your JavaScript is trying to manipulate HTML elements that haven't been loaded into the DOM yet.
(2) Your assignment of HTML content looks jumbled.
(3) Be consistent with the case in your element ID, i.e. 'DIV2' vs 'Div2'
(4) User lower case for 'document' object (credit: ThatOtherPerson)

```
<body>
<div id="DIV1">
 // Some content goes here.
</div>

<div id="DIV2">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

   var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('DIV1');
   var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('DIV2');
   MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: If you're using one of the JavaScript frameworks then the order doesn't matter. For example you can tell JQuery to wait until the contents are loaded by using $(document).ready, Angular allows you to write code using promises. It's not good practice to sprinkle JS all over a file, but putting it in files that are loaded by the browser means you have to wait. Personally I think the odd piece of JS here and there, particularly when you're developing, is no big deal.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set Div2 to Div1's innerHTML. Also, JavaScript is case sensitive - in your HTML, the id `Div2` is `DIV2`. Also, you should use `document`, not `Document`:

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('DIV1');
var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('DIV2');
MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gFN6r/.

Answer (score 4):

Right now you're setting the innerHTML to an entire div element; you want to set it to just the innerHTML.  Also, I think you want MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv **1** .innerHTML.  Also, I think the argument to `document.getElementById` is case sensitive.  You were passing `Div2` when you wanted `DIV2`

```
var MyDiv1 = Document.getElementById('DIV1');
var MyDiv2 = Document.getElementById('DIV2');
MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;
```

Also, this code will run before your DOM is ready.  You can either put this script at the bottom of your body like paislee said, or put it in your body's onload function

```
<body onload="loadFunction()">
```

and then

```
function loadFunction(){
    var MyDiv1 = Document.getElementById('DIV1');
    var MyDiv2 = Document.getElementById('DIV2');
    MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use jquery plugin to get/set the content of the div.

> var divContent = $('#'DIV1).html(); $('#'DIV2).html(divContent );

for this you need to include jquery library.

Comment: The question was not about jquery.

Answer (score 1):

function add_more() {

```
var text_count = document.getElementById('text_count').value;
var div_cmp = document.getElementById('div_cmp');
var values = div_cmp.innnerHTML;
var count = parseInt(text_count);
divContent = '';

for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

    var cmp_text = document.getElementById('cmp_name_' + i).value;
    var cmp_textarea = document.getElementById('cmp_remark_' + i).value;
    divContent += '<div id="div_cmp_' + i + '">' +
        '<input type="text" align="top" name="cmp_name[]" id="cmp_name_' + i + '" value="' + cmp_text + '" >' +
        '<textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="cmp_remark[]" id="cmp_remark_' + i + '">' + cmp_textarea + '</textarea>' +
        '</div>';
}

var newCount = count + 1;

if (document.getElementById('div_cmp_' + newCount) == null) {
    var newText = '<div id="div_cmp_' + newCount + '">' +
        '<input type="text" align="top" name="cmp_name[]" id="cmp_name_' + newCount + '" value="" >' +
        '<textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="cmp_remark[]" id="cmp_remark_' + newCount + '"  ></textarea>' +
        '</div>';
    //content = div_cmp.innerHTML;
    div_cmp.innerHTML = divContent + newText;
} else {
    document.getElementById('div_cmp_' + newCount).innerHTML = '<input type="text" align="top" name="cmp_name[]" id="cmp_name_' + newCount + '" value="" >' +
        '<textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="cmp_remark[]" id="cmp_remark_' + newCount + '"  ></textarea>';
}

document.getElementById('text_count').value = newCount;

}
```