# How to get only the contents of a div not a full page using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to be able to get only the contents of a div instead of loading the full page.

My current js is:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('file.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It's loading the whole page when I submit the form, I want it to only load the contents of one div.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below links to find out how the DIV elements can be accessed using JavaScript:

> [Get content of a DIV using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647216/get-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)
>
> [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

):

Comment: Thanks for the link, I already saw those though. I'm looking for a way to edit what I already have.