# Get content of a div before and after id (or class) with native Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying (in native Javascript, so without jQuery or anything) to get content before and after occurence of a div.

HTML:

```
<div id="thisIsWhatIWant">
  <span>foo</span>
    <div id="helloWorld">hello world</div>
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
```

So I want to get `<span>foo</span>` and `<p>bar</p>` in separate vars.

JS:

```
var beforeElement_helloWorld = ...do something to get <span>foo</span>...
var afterElement_helloWorld  = ...do something to get <p>bar</p>...
```

*note:

There may be many more divs, spans etc in the HTML example.*

Comment: Possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647216/get-content-of-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: @mrciga Absolutely no duplicate ;-)

Comment: @bvl: Please ask the main question

Comment: @kenorb I don't understand what you mean? The main question is in the question: "I want to get <span>foo</span> and <p>bar</p> in separate vars."

Comment: @bvl: Then add the question mark, if that is your main question on Q&A site as I don't see any other question marks in your post, that mean you're not asking anything and it's very low quality post.

Comment: @kenorb dude, really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
var previous = document.getElementById("helloWorld").previousElementSibling;
var next = document.getElementById("helloWorld").nextElementSibling;
```

Also read this,
The difference between previousSibling and previousElementSibling, is that previousSibling returns the previous sibling node as an element node, a text node or a comment node, while previousElementSibling returns the previous sibling node as an element node (ignores text and comment nodes).

Comment: Fantastic @roshan this is *exactly* what I'm looking for. I love jQuery, but I don't know all these native JS possibilities.