# Python set value is undefined for JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

In my main python file, I have the following code.

```
@app.route('/accounts/test/learn/medium')
def medium():
word = random.choice(os.listdir("characters/"))
return render_template('accounts/test/medium.html', word=word)
```

My HTML Template "Medium" has a div called "character" which contains the word.

```
<div id="character" style="font-weight:bold;color:red"  >{{ word }}</div>
```

My Javascript file, which I call **body onLoad** tries to set the png file for the word/character.

```
currentWord = document.getElementById("character").value
if(document.getElementById("characterPNG")!=null){
    document.getElementById("characterPNG").src = "../../../style/images/characters/png/" +currentWord+ ".png";
```

When I run the application, Python sets the word in my HTML I can see that,
but JavaScript, can't see the value of character. It rather say's

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of** http://path/**undefined.png**

Do you have any suggestions what might be wrong? Is it the sequence?

Comment: The JavaScript is running in the browser on the client side; you can't use a relative path for the image. You should use flask to supply the image URL with `url_for`.

Comment: I think the main issue is that the DIV-element does not have a value. He wants to read the HTML content (the `innerHTML` attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer [Get content of a DIV using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647216/get-content-of-a-div-using-javascript) you should use `innerHTML` instead of `value`:

```
currentWord = document.getElementById("character").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, I would make good use of [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for) from Flask to generate urls for static files, as follows:

Quoting from [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files)'s doc:

> Static Files
>
> Dynamic web applications also need static files. That’s usually where
>   the CSS and JavaScript files are coming from. Ideally your web server
>   is configured to serve them for you, but during development Flask can
>   do that as well. **Just create a folder called static in your package or
>   next to your module and it will be available at /static on the
>   application.**

So, after you create a static folder, just reference it in your template with `url_for` method pointing out as well the filename:

```
<img id="characterPNG" src={{url_for('static', filename=word+'.png')}}></img>
```

Comment: I totally aggree with you, but the question was about the undefined value