# How do I copy specific text from one area to another?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy a specific part of a sentence from a div to another and input it to another area using JavaScript.

```
<div id="copyfromhere">This is +how+ it works.</div>
<div id="pastehere"></div>
```

I'd like to copy the part in between the + symbols. The + symbols are included in the original sentence.

Comment: show us something you have tried and didn't work?

Comment: Do you always want to copy something between + symbols?  Might there be other + symbols in the sentence?

Comment: You can get help from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647216/get-content-of-a-div-using-javascript

Comment: There would be no other + symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the text from div and split it based on '+', which will return the array, then you can access that arrays 2nd value indexed at 1.

```
var pastehereDiv = document.querySelector("#pastehere");
var copyfromDiv = document.querySelector("#copyfromhere")
pastehereDiv.textContent = copyfromDiv.textContent.split('+')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var copy = function() {
  // grab the origin and destination divs
  var origin = document.getElementById("copyfromhere");
  var destination = document.getElementById("pastehere");
  
  // get the text from the origin, split on "+" and then get the second element in the array
  var text = from.innerText.split("+")[1];
  // apply that text to the destination div
  destination.innerText = text;
}
```

```html
<div id="copyfromhere">This is +how+ it works.</div>
<div id="pastehere"></div>

<button id="copy" onClick="copy()">Copy</button>
```

Obviously this will only work if there aren't any other `+`s in your origin div.