# How to know the content of a li in a list?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JavaScript and i run into a lot of problems, most of them I already found a solution, but there is a problem that I don't know how to fix it, it might seem sample but I struggled a lot with this problem and didn't found an answer.

So lets say that I have a `<ul>` like the given one:

```
<ul>
  <li>my content 1</li>
  <li>my content 2</li>
  <li>my content 3</li>
</ul>
```

How am I supposed to get the content from that `<li>` to use it in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by “get the content ... use it in my code”? What is your aim? What have you tried so far?

Comment: there are 3 li's. from which one you want to get the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's already an answer for your struggle: [Get content of a DIV using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647216/get-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)

In your case something like this would do:

`var list = document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];`

`var content = list.getElementsByTagName("LI")[0].innerHTML;`

Notice the `[0]` - that would select the first item. If you want the content from the second or third you will need to change it to `[1] or [2]`

Comment: Thanks that actually helped my problem. I didn't thought it was that simple...

Comment: @masterRed try to always search first before asking a question, this will save you so much time.

Answer (score 0):

with `getElementsByTagName`

```
function example1() {
        let list = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, (item)=>console.log(item.innerHTML));
    }
```

with `querySelectorAll`

```
  function example2() {
        document.querySelectorAll('li')
            .forEach((li) => {
                console.log(li.innerHTML)
            });
    }
```

[Es6]  convert an HtmlCollection to an Array with spread

```
function example3() {
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    let list = [...elements]
    //use with forEach
    list.forEach(item=>{console.log(item.innerHTML)})
    // or use direct
    console.log(list[0].innerHTML)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the li(s) like so

```
 var li= document.querySelector('li');
```

then grab the text content from the li

```
 var liContent = li.textContent;
 console.log(liContent);
```

same thing but for a list of li

initializing an empty array

```js
var listItemsContent = [];
    
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach((li) => {
     //pushing into the empty array
     listItemsContent.push(li.textContent);
     console.log(li.textContent)
});

console.log(listItemsContent);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>my content 1</li>
  <li>my content 2</li>
  <li>my content 3</li>
</ul>
```